# Does Time Machine fix ownership of files when restoring from another Mac?

Tags: macos, mac, time-machine

My computer recently crashed with no backup of Time Machine. I'm having issues getting a clean install to install on my hard drive (it won't let me do a fresh install from my Boot USB disk).

I am however having more luck using a Time Machine backup from my girlfriends MacBook Pro.

Am I going to run into any ownership issues when restoring Lion from another computer its Time Machine backup?

Comment: Have you tried doing a clean install by starting up from the recovery partition?

Comment: Yeah, clean install only goes as far as the restart, once the computer restarts it can't find the boot drive (ie hard drive it installed onto). The only drive it can find as bootable is the thumb drive Mountain Lion installer I've made.

Comment: There are a few problems with your question. If you fix them, probably we can help you better. Elaborate on the quoted text: 1. What “luck” are you having “using” a Time Machine backup? 2. Which “ownership issues”? Ownership can mean many things in the context of this question. 3. This doesn’t make sense: “restoring Lion from another computer its Time Machine Backup”.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, if you use Migration Assistant (either the standalone application or during the installation of OSX) to move files from Time Machine to any computer there is no problem. I've moved users before from one computer to the other. If you copy directly from the hard drive you might run into issues, but Migration Assistant does the trick.